# Is there any performance advantage of initialising an integer array with memset instead of default zero initialisation like array[10]={0}?

Tags: c++, arrays, memset

Given that memset can be only used to initialise an integer array with the values 0 or -1 what would be the reason that you use it for zero initialisation. Does its efficacy lie solely in string initialisation?

```
array[10];
memset(array,0,sizeof(array)); 

array[10]={0};
```

Isn`t the latter way always the better?

Comment: Define "always". Can you do the second form after the fact?

Comment: If this is for C strings, you're better off using `std::string` and not worrying about this.

Comment: Can `memset` only use the values 0 or -1?

Comment: Note that efficacy != efficiency.

Comment: In general, for simple things like this, the compiler will do at least as good a job as you can do, and often will do a better job.

Comment: _"Given that memset can be only used to initialise an integer array with the values 0 or -1 what would be the reason that you use it for zero initialisation."_ is wrong. You can memset with any value.

Comment: The "problem" with `memset` is that it only writes **byte** values to memory. You can't use it to write arbitrary values to multi-byte types.

Answer (score 2):

> Isn`t the latter way always the better?

Code for clarity unless some reason compels otherwise.

---

`array[10] = {0};` is clear and clean, yet not a solution for a subsequent zero-ing.

`memset(array, 0, sizeof array);` can be done multiple times throughout the life of `array`.  `memset()` is not really *initializing*, but *assignment*.

> Is there any performance advantage

A good compiler will emit efficient code either way.  If a performance advantage exists, it may indicate a weak compiler.